# I can't figure out how the heck to get a UIButton to activate the iPhone LED

Tags: iphone, xcode, swift

I have the code.

```
@IBAction func toggleFlash(sender: AnyObject) {

func toggleFlash() {
    let device = AVCaptureDevice.defaultDeviceWithMediaType(AVMediaTypeVideo)
    if (device.hasTorch) {
        device.lockForConfiguration(nil)
        if (device.torchMode == AVCaptureTorchMode.On) {
            device.torchMode = AVCaptureTorchMode.Off
        } else {
            device.setTorchModeOnWithLevel(1.0, error: nil)
        }
        device.unlockForConfiguration()
    }
}
}
```

I connected a button to that code. The iPhone LED won't turn on. I also imported the following:

```
import UIKit

import AVFoundation

import MessageUI

import UIKit

import CoreGraphics
```

And added them as binaries.

I don't know what I am doing wrong.
Please help. THANKS!

Answer (score 1):

You've erroneously *nested* an internal function *inside* your IBAction function

```
func toggleFlash() {
}
```

Therefore, when the button is pressed, your IBAction function is called, but the inner function, which is uninvoked by anything inside the IBAction function, would not be called.

I suggest you remove the inner function lines shown and try again.

And of course, use the debugger or print statements to confirm that your IBAction function is being called after you do that.

I can't guarantee the light will come on, but I would start by getting your IBAction function working in general.  This is the function you showed after removing the nested function from inside it:

```
@IBAction func toggleFlash(sender: AnyObject) {
    let device = AVCaptureDevice.defaultDeviceWithMediaType(AVMediaTypeVideo)
    if (device.hasTorch) {
        device.lockForConfiguration(nil)
        if (device.torchMode == AVCaptureTorchMode.On) {
            device.torchMode = AVCaptureTorchMode.Off
        } else {
            device.setTorchModeOnWithLevel(1.0, error: nil)
        }
       device.unlockForConfiguration()
    }
}
```

For future reference, you *can* put a function inside a function (nested functions) in Swift, but the inner function isn't called unless you invoke it.

Example:

```
func a(i : Int) {
    func b() {
         var j = i * 2
         println("doubled: " + j)
    }
    b()
}
```

Comment: You are my hero! Thank you so much!

Comment: @John - Thanks. Glad to help! Could you click the grey √ next to the answer to accept it?